# How to create parent for a child?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to create a parent for a child.

If I have `<a href=#></a>` I need to have like

```
 <div>
     <a href=#></a>
 </div>
```

I have many data, that I'm receiving from the HTTP request, so it needs to be done automatically.

What I've tried and where I'm stuck?

I was trying like:

```
elementForParrent.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', '<span class="product-slider--item">');
elementForParrent.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '</span>');
```

but after inserting this way html element, the first one had automatically closed `</span>` tag.

I was trying like:

```
elementForParrent.insertAdjacentText('beforebegin', '<span class="product-slider--item">');
elementForParrent.insertAdjacentText('afterend', '</span>');
```

But then, my span tags were written to html with quotes: "" and it wasn't working.

My question is: is it possible to create parent for a child on the fly? I know that parents can create children, like in real life, is that impossible to create parent for a child (like in real life?)

Kind Regards,

Gregoraz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. It creates and element and wraps it on the existing element thus creating a parent node

```js
var e=document.querySelector('a');
var p = e.parentNode;
var w = document.createElement('div');
p.replaceChild(w, e);
w.appendChild(e);
```

```html
 <a href=#>ff</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done as follows:

```
parent.appendChild(el);
```

What you'd do is, you create your `parent` element and then you append your `href` to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this also, create html constant variable and assign html that you want to get as parent,

```
const html = `
   <span class="product-slider--item"></span>
`;

elementForParrent.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', html);
```